# Newsstand app shows a blue circle under the icon

Tags: ios7, newsstand-kit

I m new to Newsstand app in iOS. When i run my app in the device/emulator , a blue circle is showing under it.

As i know it shows that a new download available. But even though i read the pdf which is downloaded. It still shows.

I want to know how to remove the blue circle in the newsstand. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset the application badge:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```